# can not resolve symbol AdView

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, adview

I want to add AdView in my app, but in Main Activity, there is a problem, which shows that "AdView can not resolve a symbol" and also another problem, which shows that "can not resolve symbol InterstatialAd". Please help me. Below is my code.

[image]

Comment: Your app is not be able to find updated *google play services lib*.

Comment: Sir if you have then share with me

Answer (score 0):

One common reason for this error is that the Google Mobile Ads SDK hasn't been imported into the project. I'd recommend having a look at these resources if you haven't already:

- [The Android AdMob quick start guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)
- [Video walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLLLRUPICcc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c) of setting up the Mobile Ads SDK in Android